# Retrieve encapsulated content from Bouncy Castle's CMSAuthenticatedData [Java]

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I'm using the CMSAuthenticatedData from the Bouncy Castle library, version 146. I can create it correctly, verified by inspecting the ASN.1 dump, but I can't seem to retrieve the content.

The authenticated data object is created with a generator, like this:

```
CMSAuthenticatedDataGenerator generator = new CMSAuthenticatedDataGenerator();
CMSProcessableByteArray myContent = new CMSProcessableByteArray(myBytes);
CMSAuthenticatedData cmsData = generator.generate(myContent, myMacCalculator);
```

cmsData is then serialized with .getEncoded(), sent to the server, and deserialized with the byte[] constructor. From the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3852#section-9.1), I see myBytes should be in the encapContentInfo field inside the AuthenticatedData object, but I can't get it. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
// The original byte array I want to retrieve is 633 bytes long.

cmsData.getEncoded();
// returns ASN.1 for authData OID and AuthenticatedData object. Size: 724

cmsData.getContentInfo();
// Same as cmsData.getEncoded(). Size: 724

cmsData.getContentInfo().getContent().getDERObject().getEncoded();
// returns ASN.1 for AuthenticatedData object. Size: 703
```

So, is this even possible, or should I roll out my own implementation, parsing the ASN.1 byte array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of research, I found a solution using `org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.AuthenticatedData`:

```
CMSAuthenticatedData cmsData; // <- this is the object created.
byte[] cmsBytes = cmsData.getContentInfo().getContent().getDERObject().getEncoded();
ASN1Sequence byteSeq = (ASN1Sequence) ASN1Object.fromByteArray(rawAuthenticatedDataBytes)
AuthenticatedData authData = new AuthenticatedData(byteSeq);
byte[] contentBytes = authData.getEncapsulatedContentInfo().getContent().getDERObject().getEncoded()
```

I sure hope this is not the simplest way, but it was the only one I found.